# Beginner python code won't print in cmd

Tags: python, cmd

I've written this short segment to print ice-cream flavors, but when I run it in the command prompt nothing happens, and when I tried to output it to a .txt file I also got nothing.

```
def favorite_ice_cream():
    ice_cream_flavor=[
    "Death by chocolate",
    "Arboretum breeze",
    "Bittersweet mint",
    "Cookies-N-Cream"
]
print(ice_cream_flavor[3])

favorite_ice_cream()
```

Comment: How exactly are you running it in command prompt?

Comment: You define `ice_cream_flavor` inside a function.  When you try to print it, it is out of scope.  This code shoudn't just do nothing, it should throw an error.

Comment: @roganjosh `ice_cream_flavor` is a list.

Comment: @chrisz My _guess_ is that the print statement is actually inside the function in OPs real code. But this is a guess...

Comment: @chrisz The indentation issue might be from copy/pasting to SO though.

Comment: @DavidG I hadn't even thought of that, but I'd imagine that was the intent and the indentation was off

Answer (score 3):

The indentation of your code is significant.  If what you posted in your question is accurate (e.g., not a simple mis-formatting when you asked the question), then your `print` statement, as indicated in the comments, is not inside the function.

You want:

```
def favorite_ice_cream():
    ice_cream_flavor=[
    "Death by chocolate",
    "Arboretum breeze",
    "Bittersweet mint",
    "Cookies-N-Cream"
    ]
    print(ice_cream_flavor[3])

favorite_ice_cream()
```

Which, when run, produces:

```
Cookies-N-Cream
```